# How find $dy/dx$ $y= \frac{x^2+\sin2x}{2x+\cos^2 x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$dy/dx\space\space y= \frac{x^2+\sin2x}{2x+\cos^2x}$$

Comment: I have no idea what $sen$ is, but: quotient rule, [product rule,] chain rule.

Comment: Sen is closely related to but not as much fun as sin.

Comment: sen is sine in Spanish.

Comment: @user73276 : Are you quite sure you didn't mean $d/dx$ where you wrote $dy/dx$?  Writing $dy/dx\  f(x)$ where $d/dx\ f(x)$ is needed is a commonplace clumsy mistake of beginners.

Comment: What does $ \frac d{dx} \sqrt[3]{5+4x^3}$ have to do with it?

Comment: I also found it odd, but the teacher put dy/dx so in the test.

Comment: Sounds like the teacher is selling oranges short of a basket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) and the chain rule to find $\frac {dy}{dx} = y'$ given $$y= \frac{x^2+\sin2x}{2x+\cos^2x}$$

Given a quotient of functions: $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$

In your case, we have $$f(x) = \frac{x^2+\sin2x}{2x+\cos^2x}$$

So put $g(x) = x^2 + \sin 2x,\;$ and $\;h(x) = 2x + \cos^2x$.

Now, $g'(x) = 2x + 2\cos 2x,\;$ and $\;h'(x) = 2 - 2\cos x \sin x = 2 - \sin(2x)$.

So $$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$ $$f'(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(2x + 2\cos 2x)(2x + \cos^2 x) + (x^2 + \sin 2x)(2 - \sin 2x)}{\left(2x + \cos^2 x\right)^2}$$

The rest is of the work is merely algebraic simplification.

Comment: clean explanation +1

Comment: Very Clean Amzoti. +1

Answer (score 0):

Remember the [quotient rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule):  if $f(x)=\frac {g(x)}{h(x)}$ then $f'(x)=\frac {(h(x)g'(x)-g(x)h'(x)}{h^2(x)}$.  Can you take the derivative of the numerator and denominator, then plug into this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula

if $y=\frac {f(x)}{g(x)} $ then $ \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}y=\left( \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)} - \frac {g'(x)}{g(x)} \right)\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}$

$$  \frac{\mathrm d y}{\mathrm d x}=\left(  \frac{(2x+ 2 \cos 2x)}{\mathrm (x²+\sin2x)} - \frac{(2-2\cos x \sin x)}{\mathrm (2x+\cos^2x)} \right) \frac{x²+\sin2x}{2x+\cos^2x}$$